# What does "Enable AirPlay over WAN" do?

Tags: network, airplay, airport

What does AirPlay over WAN do? I have an AirPort Express 802.11n. This was the last generation to hook directly into the outlet.[image: AirPlay over WAN]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it refers to accepting airplay connections from computers connected to the wired ethernet port on the AirPort Express. The port's primary purpose when the AirPortExpress was first released was to connect to a cable or DSL modem. Apple and many other home router makers refer to this as the WAN connection. However, I think it only supports AirPlay when the AirPort Express is being used to bridge wired devices onto a WiFi network.

I base this on my interpretation of [this review of the AirPort Express](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-reviews/31800-apple-airport-express-2012-reviewed) on Small Net Builder:

> Since the Music screen is unique to the Express, I grabbed a copy of it. The screenshot below shows that the controls are pretty simple. The Enable AirPlay over WAN feature really works, since that's where the iTunes server I used for a quick test sat. Administration from the WAN worked just fine, too.

Comment: I don't think so. My parents have multiple AExpress routers hooked up with LAN connections and they are able to stream to all the different speaker zones without WLAN connectivity on those routers.

Comment: So you are implying that they don't have the "Enable AirPlay over WAN" option enabled?

Comment: It's been configured that way for a couple years, so no - they wouldn't have had that option.

Answer (score 2):

If the AirPort Express is being used to extend your network and plugged into another router via the WAN port, you will be able to use AirPlay from devices connected to your other router.

Answer (score 1):

It allows the use of AirPlay from outside your private network. WAN= Wide Area Network.

Comment: How can this be of any use?